# Hide mysql AI UID's, unique and not unique results, always same length

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, encoding

I need to convert mysql auto-increment bigint uid's (1-20 digit) into strings of the same length for public displaying and url's (hiding the real uid).

I also need to create 3 variants, one that creates the same encrypted string each time per id (these all must be the same length (10-50 alphanumeric)), one that creates a different/random string each time so the id displayed is never the same but can still be retrieved (these all must be the same length (10-50 alphanumeric)). 
The last is a short id (for user id's), displaying the least amount of characters (compressed string), alphanumeric, always the same per id (always the same length, as short as possible); this one is only created once per session so can take longer or use more resources to create.

```
// METHOD 1
$id = '1';
displayed: 64359b7192746a14740a
 (same each time, all id's always displayed at same length)

// METHOD 2
$id = '1000000000000000000';
displayed: 746a14740ad4bb7afe4eht36nh
           146a7492719b3564094eyu8o0p
           fe7abbd40a7416fd90012fvd3e
 (different each time, all id's always displayed at same length)

// METHOD 3
$userid = '2598624451675864259';
displayed: aw8qg07nzq
 (same each time, all id's always displayed at same length)
```

I need a basic 2 way encryption or encoding method, speed/less resources is priority over security, but should not be easily guessable as to avoid counting id's to determine activity.

I tried md5 hash but dont want to md5 search or store the hash in the db.
I have tried other numeric only ways, padding the id's to 20, but end up with longer than wanted 60 character strings. Tried using base_convert for numeric but the id's are to long and max out.

If anybody can point me the right way for any of these I would appreciate it.

Comment: thanks for the unexplained down-vote unknown person. If you did this because this question has been asked, it is different than the many others I have read! If its because I did not show code, then you did not read my question; no point showing what I said didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Abandon having the id in the first place.  Simply create something random, such as

```
mysql> SELECT MD5(NOW());
+----------------------------------+
| MD5(NOW())                       |
+----------------------------------+
| 9fc432bc91593e8beaf6ffb5b9bf83a0 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then use that string as your `PRIMARY KEY`.  `MD5`, for example is only one-way, but I argue that that does not really matter.  All you are avoiding with 2-way is some hacker playing around with ids that don't belong to him.

If MD5 is too long, pick something shorter, but check for dups when a new "id" is given out.

As long as the user and the urls give you `9fc432bc91593e8beaf6ffb5b9bf83a0`, there is question about decryption speed -- it is just a lookup.

Comment: `MD5(NOW())` isn't really random. :\

Comment: OK, not "random" in that it is deterministic (always returns the same value for the same argument).  But it is "random" if you use it as, say, the `PRIMARY KEY`:  Each new `INSERT` will seemingly pick some random place to put the row.  That leads to hurting caching.